# HOw to inject an Angular component to a table's cell

Tags: angular

I want to create a table in which its cells are components

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableHeaders"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableHeaders"></tr>

<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>actions</th>
      <ng-container *matCellDef="let element">            
         <td>
            <!-- inject the element here -->
            <!-- the element can be any Angular component -->
            <!-- how Angular knows which element to inject in which cell -->
         </td>            
      </ng-container>
   </ng-container>
</table>
```

```
tableHeaders = ["actions"];

dataSouces=[
  Component1,
  Component2
  ...
]


@component({...})
export class Component1{}

@component({...})
export class Component2{}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Why dont you just... use the component(s) in question?!

Comment: how Angular knows exactly which component to inject in which cell

Comment: Angular doesn't know, but you are supposed to know